# Enable two-way ssl for Oracle MAF applications on Windows 10

Tags: ssl, uwp, oracle-maf

We are implementing a MAF application on Window 10 (UWP) platform. There is a requirement for using client certificate in communicating with our server via HTTPS. We are using MAF 2.3.2.

We have generated client certificate (in p12 format) and set up the server side (WebLogic) properly. When installing the client certificate on a browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), we can successfully communicate with the server. Believing we have set up the environment properly, We then follow very closely the steps outlined in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf230/mobile/develop-maf/GUID-3975EBAB-DB9E-4BC2-B814-619F30AF897D.htm#GUID-921E4406…  to implement the 2-way SSL on our MAF application.

1. First we installed the .p12 certificate using Windows Certificate Import Wizard. The certificate is successfully installed to the "Personal" store of the certificate store.
2. We then specified "p12" as the client certificate extension in maf-application.xml, as shown below:

   ```
   <adfmf:application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adfmf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf"
              version="1.0" name="<OurAppName>" id="com.XXX.ID"
              appControllerFolder="ApplicationController"
              listener-class="com.XXX.application.LifeCycleListenerImpl"
              client-ssl-certificate-extension="p12">
   ... ...
   </adfmf:application>
   ```
3. We also specified connection using HTTPS, which is the one requiring client-authentication.

```
<Reference name="IOM_LOGIN" className="oracle.adf.model.connection.adfmf.LoginConnection"
         adfCredentialStoreKey="IOM_LOGIN" partial="false" manageInOracleEnterpriseManager="true" deployable="true"
         xmlns="">
<Factory className="oracle.adf.model.connection.adfmf.LoginConnectionFactory"/>
<RefAddresses>
  <XmlRefAddr addrType="adfmfLogin">
    <Contents>
      <login url="https://our-server:port/Login"/>
      <logout url="https:/our-server:port/Login"/>
      <stsModule/>
      <stsEndpoint/>
      <stsAppliesTo/>
      <stsLifetime value="3600"/>
      <authenticationMode value="local"/>
      <idleTimeout value="0"/>
      <sessionTimeout value="0"/>
      <maxFailuresBeforeCredentialCleared value="3"/>
      <rememberCredentials>
        <enableRememberUserName value="true"/>
        <rememberUserNameDefault value="true"/>
        <enableRememberPassword value="false"/>
        <enableStayLoggedIn value="false"/>
      </rememberCredentials>
      <accessControl/>
      <userObjectFilter/>
    </Contents>
  </XmlRefAddr>
</RefAddresses>
```

4. Then we deployed and ran the application. At runtime, MAF presented a login page. We entered the user name and password. But MAF responded with a "Invalid credential" message. I thought MAF would prompt us to select a client certificate (as in the case when we were testing with the browser). However it didn't happen.

Note that, if the server does not enforce client-authentication (i.e. when our service uses one-way SSL), the connection is working fine.

Has anyone done two-way SSL authentication for MAF application on Windows 10? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you give any credentials for generating p12 certificate? If yes, try with those username and password.  
I have done the same but the difference is that in my case i used Oracle MCS's end points. and the username and password was corresponds to the MCS

Comment: No. The P12 certificate was exported from JKS. It has a keypass. I am interested in understanding 1) which platform you are using, Windows 10 or Android, (2) how/where you place your client certificate. Thanks.

Comment: It was for IOS. For MCS there is a base url to enter that was used as the login and logout url.